# UDP multicast receives 2^24 bytes of data which should be impossible

Tags: c, sockets, winsock, multicast, recvfrom

have a stand alone PC running VS6 on WinXP - yes ancient technology.
I am porting a C code app from Linux.
Stuck on multicast problem

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>      /* for printf(), fprintf() */
#include <conio.h>
#include <winsock.h>    /* for socket(),... */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* for exit() */

#define MAXRECVSTRING 255  /* Longest string to receive */

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char msg[100];
    char loopchar = 0;
    int iOptVal = 0;
    char iOptVal2 = 1;
    int iLenOptVal = sizeof(int);
    int result = -1;
    int retval = -1;
    int set_option_on = 1;

    int sock;                         /* Socket */
    struct sockaddr_in multicastAddr; /* Multicast Address */
    char *multicastIP;                /* IP Multicast Address */
    unsigned short multicastPort;     /* Port */
    char recvString[MAXRECVSTRING+1]; /* Buffer for received string */
    unsigned int recvStringLen;       /* Length of received string */
    struct ip_mreq multicastRequest;  /* Multicast address join structure */
    WSADATA wsaData;                  /* Structure for WinSock setup communication */

    if (argc != 3)    /* Test for correct number of arguments */
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Usage: %s <Multicast IP> <Multicast Port>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    multicastIP = argv[1];        /* First arg: Multicast IP address (dotted quad) */
    //WW Silversilsied  //WW SilversilsiedmulticastIP = inet_addr("224.000.010.101");       /* First arg: Multicast IP address (dotted quad) */
    //multicastIP = inet_addr("224.000.010.101");       /* First arg: Multicast IP address (dotted quad) */
    multicastPort = atoi(argv[2]);/* Second arg: Multicast port */
    //multicastPort = 6600);/* Second arg: Multicast port */

    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &wsaData) != 0) /* Load Winsock 2.0 DLL */
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "WSAStartup() failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Create a best-effort datagram socket using UDP */
    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) < 0)
    {
        printf("\nsocket() failed - error = %d\n", sock);
    }

    /* Construct bind structure */
    memset(&multicastAddr, 0, sizeof(multicastAddr));   /* Zero out structure */
    multicastAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;                 /* Internet address family */
    multicastAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);  /* Any incoming interface */
    multicastAddr.sin_port = htons(multicastPort);      /* Multicast port */

    /* Bind to the multicast port */
    retval = bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &multicastAddr, sizeof(multicastAddr));
    if (retval < 0)
    {
        printf("\nbind() failed - error = %d\n", retval);
    }

#if 0
    /* Specify the multicast group */
    multicastRequest.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr(multicastIP);

    /* Accept multicast from any interface */
    multicastRequest.imr_interface.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    /* Join the multicast address */
    //if (setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (char*)&multicastRequest, sizeof(multicastRequest)) < 0)
    result = setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char*)&set_option_on, sizeof(set_option_on));
    if (result < 0)
    {
        printf("\n setsockopt() failed");
        perror("    setsockopt  ");
    }

    /* Receive a single datagram from the server */
    while(1)
    {
         if ((recvStringLen = recvfrom(sock, recvString, MAXRECVSTRING, 0, NULL, 0)) < 0)
        {
            printf("\nrecvfrom() failed");
        }
    Sleep(1000);
    }
#else
    strcpy(msg,"default test message");
    struct sockaddr_in address1;
    int len;
    int bytes_sent = -1;
    memset(&address1, 0, sizeof(address1));
    address1.sin_family = AF_INET;  
    address1.sin_port = multicastPort;
    address1.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(multicastIP);
    //msg = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    //socklen_t len;
    //size = strlen(msg);
    if ((recvStringLen = recvfrom(sock, recvString, 1024, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&address1, &len)) < 0)

    {
        printf("\nrecvfrom() failed ");
        perror("    recvfrom  ");
    }else{

    recvString[recvStringLen] = '\0';
    printf("Received: %d bytes %s\n", recvStringLen,recvString);    /* Print the received string */
    perror("    received from  ");
    }

    bytes_sent = sendto(sock,
                            msg,
                            sizeof(msg),
                            0,
                            (struct sockaddr*)&address1,
                            sizeof(address1));
    printf("bytes sent = %d \n", bytes_sent);
    printf("size of msg = %d \n ", sizeof(msg));
    perror(   "sendto  ");
#endif

    getch();

    closesocket(sock);
    WSACleanup();   /* Cleanup Winsock */

    exit(0);
    return 0;

}
```

When I single step through, I get a successful socket creation and valid socket descriptor.
I get a successful bind, at which point the port shows up as udp when I do a cmd line netstat -p UDP -a

setsockopt also completes without error.

When I step through the recvfrom it receives 2^24 bytes all of which are the same -52
The machine is stand alone, not on a network.

Comment: What does the 'I got' mean? Does this code really compile? Are you really executing this code? What is the type and value of `recvStringLen `? and the value of `MAXRECVSTRING`? NB It isn't correct to call `perror()` *after* another `printf()`. You must call it immediately after the system call that returned the error.

Comment: You receive one packet claiming to be that length, or several, adding up to that length?  What is the value of `MAXRECVSTRING`?  What is the type of `recvStringLen`?

Comment: In the Winsock API, functions like `recvfrom()` return `SOCKET_ERROR` on error, which you should be checking against specifically. This may be your problem.

Comment: This is just a snippet of the code.   The whole app is about 3 times this long.   Should I post that???    MAXRECVSTRING is #defined as 255

Comment: recvStringLen is an int   I'll move the perror()'s to right after the system call and see if anything is reported.  Using Wireshark there is no network activity that would account for this huge amount of data.     "I got" ended up in this text in error.      And yes it all compiles and runs.  I can easily post the entire code.  If I can figure how to embed it into a reply window.

Comment: This inrush of data seems to occur on the initial receive attempt.   I put the receive in a loop and it does not occur in subsequent iterations.  Which leads me to another problem,   the recv should just set there and wait until it receives packets.

Answer (score 2):

recvString is 256 bytes long, but your recvFrom() is asking for up to 1024 bytes.

Comment: I made both numbers the same, it does not change the incoming 2^24 bytes of data incoming.

Comment: OK, good to know. I just noticed another issue: you need to set `len = sizeof(address1)` before every call to `recvfrom()`.